# How to prevent function call on submit form if required fields are not filled out?

Tags: javascript, html

I have form with required inputs, it actually sees empty field and shows message, but it calls function from submit button

```
<form action="">
    <input required id="1" type="text">
    <button type="submit" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `onclick` listener will run whenever the button is clicked, no matter what.

You want the function to run only when the form starts to be submitted, so attach a `submit` listener to the form instead:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="calculate()">
    <input required id="1" type="text">
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

```js
const calculate = (e) => {
  console.log('calculating');
}
```

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="calculate()">
    <input required id="1" type="text">
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

If at all possible, it would be much better to attach the event listener properly using Javascript instead of an inline HTML attribute:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', calculate);
```

```js
const calculate = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('calculating');
};
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', calculate);
```

```html
<form action="">
    <input required id="1" type="text">
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```